# web3.js: How to convert Wei to Ether?

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethereumjs

Im trying to covnert wei to ether in my node.js script

```
let myBalanceWei = web3.eth.getBalance('0xF33b5a2B692bE695d6FD6f3136eB8919f2666e3a').then(console.log)
let balance = web3.utils.fromWei(myBalanceWei, 'ether').then(console.log)
```

When I run this i get a

```
throw new Error('Please pass numbers as strings or BN objects to avoid precision errors.');
```

I tried to convert it to a bigNumber according tot he web3.js documentation but than i get an undefined error.

So how can i use a varibable as input to convert Wei to ether?
I know it requires a string but how can I fix this?

Comment: Variable `myBalanceWei` is not initialized at the time of usage. You should put the entire `web3.utils.toWei(myBalanceWei, 'ether')` inside the `then` of `web3.eth.getBalance`.

Comment: And you don't need a `then` for `web3.utils.toWei`, since t is not an asynchronous function.

Comment: Finally, `myBalanceWei` is **already in wei**!!!

Comment: sorry, correct is fromWei to ether. I tried your way like this: let myBalanceWei = web3.eth.getBalance('0xF33b5a2B692bE695d6FD6f3136eB8919f2666e3a').then(web3.utils.fromWei(myBalanceWei, 'ether')).then(console.log) when i run this i get the initialize error you are mentioning

Comment: let myBalanceWei = web3.eth.getBalance('0xF33b5a2B692bE695d6FD6f3136eB8919f2666e3a').then(web3.utils.fromWei(myBalanceWei, 'ether')).then(console.log)
                                                                                                             ^

ReferenceError: Cannot access 'myBalanceWei' before initialization

Comment: I've already explained that `web3.utils.toWei` is not asynchronous. Same goes for `web3.utils.fromWei`.

Comment: And you're not writing the first `then` correctly. It takes a function, not a value (or afunction-call). The whole thing is totally messed up.

Comment: can you please share the correct code, im kinda standing besides me right now, because even if i  split everything up into constants i get same error, so it would be much easier if you could share the 1 line of code

Comment: than, then it all gives me the same erroor

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because after explaining your errors in a few comments to your question, you asked "can you please share the correct code", which I did, i.e., fixing **your specific code**. In response, you first accepted the answer, and stated that it indeed works. Then, you started taking out all of your frustration of not being able to understand fundamental concepts of this mechanism, with a ton of swearing and cursing. This is not the way to go when asking for help here!

Comment: I could show you how to do this via `async` / `await`, but then, being that you lack basic understanding of these concepts, you'd start moaning about not being able to call the `async` function from other places in your code (and you'd probably add even more swearing). So it seems pointless at that point.

Comment: you could just make a simple tutorial in pure javascript and sahre it with evveryone,a s you see neither web3js nor any fucking tutorials around make any fucking sense

Answer (score 3):

A. In the context of a script, try this:

```
web3.eth.getBalance('0xF33b5a2B692bE695d6FD6f3136eB8919f2666e3a').then(
    function (weiBalance) {
        let ethBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(weiBalance, 'ether');
        console.log(ethBalance);
    }
);
```

B. On the truffle command line (i.e., via truffle develop), try this...

You can use arrow notation instead, to get it down to 1 line.
a. For instance, if you are checking the balance of accounts[0], you could use:

truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]).then(i => {console.log(web3.utils.fromWei(i, "ether"))})

That will simply return the value in ETH to the console.

b. With minor modifications to the internal function body (in {}), you could pass it back to an already declared local variable, instead, etc:

truffle(develop)> let myVar

truffle(develop)> web3.eth.getBalance(accounts[0]).then(i => {myVar = web3.utils.fromWei(i, "ether")})

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: this works, but do i need to write all of this in a function like this?

Comment: @charliebrown: What do you mean "write all of this in a function like this"? I didn't write it in a function.

Comment: the then statement has a function, this function (weiBalance) {
        let ethBalance = web3.utils.fromWei(weiBalance, 'ether');
        console.log(ethBalance);
    }

Comment: and why does everyone say i have to use async functions when fetching info froom the blockchain?

Comment: @charliebrown: `then` takes a function as input. When you call it with `console.log`, you are passing a function to it just as well. The function is called `log`, and it belongs to a global object named `console`.

Comment: @charliebrown: Using `then` means that you are resolving the promise returned from an async function. You can also use an async function here instead.

Comment: @charliebrown: You need to: 1. Google "Javascript async await". 2. Read [web3.js official documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/).

Comment: and if i write it like you i cant even turn the output into a variable that i can use somewhere, you shown me some ridiculous way dude- i dont like that, if i do it liek that im stuck in this function, besiides its not even async- like the get balance should be async

Comment: and where do you even get the wait balance from- your answer is worse than the shit that i try